# Easy way to upgrade RXJS imports to lettables?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to upgrade our Angular app at work... and want to do our RXJS imports correctly using lettables. We have over 2000 source files and thousands of errors about our imports like:

```
error TS2339: Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observer"' has no exported member 'Observer'.
```

I know we're suppose to change our imports to stuff like:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
```

But is there a way or a tool that can do this or most of it by hand for us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an easy upgrade route: install `rxjs-compat` alongside `rxjs` version 6. Doing so will allow you to continue to use RxJS-v5-style imports and dot-chained operators.

For an upgrade route that breaks with the RxJS-v5 practices, there is [`rxjs-tslint`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs-tslint): a set of rules that can be used to automatically upgrade your RxJS-v5 code to use the new, RxJS-v6 imports and to upgrade dot-chained operators to use `pipe` instead.

For more information, see the [migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md).

Comment: This is great as it cleans up the imports but is there anyway to clean up all the things like "Observable.of" or "<Observable>blah.share()"?

Comment: If `rxjs-tslint` doesn't upgrade `Observable.of`, I would suggest you raise an issue for it. `rxjs-tslint` will convert dot-chained operators like `blah.share()` to `blah.pipe(share())`.

Comment: Sweet ok. This is fantastic. No idea this existed. Thank you!